# JRuby Profligacy, JDialog dispose

Tags: ruby, swing, jruby, jdialog

i'm trying to trigger the JDialog#dispose in a JButton

```
class SettingsDialog < JDialog
  include_package 'javax.swing'
  include Profligacy
  def initialize(frame, modal)
     layout = "[ save ]"


    @ui = Swing::LEL.new(JFrame, layout) do |c, i|
      c.save = @save_button = JButton.new "Save"
      i.save = { action: method(:save) }
    end
  end

  def save(type, event)
    self.dispose
  end
end
```

the output is: nothing :( and JDialog still open

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: try doing things in "plain" (ruby) swing-style - it's hard to follow since Profligacy has not been updated for a few years now. simple Java tutorials might help you if you understand how to do those calls in JRuby (not hard at all) ... good luck!